# Preventing my picturebox from leaving the bottom of my form

Tags: c#, winforms, bounds

I'm having an issue with my picturebox, leaving the bottom of my form. Basically I'm creating a mini game where you control your ship with the arrow key up and arrow key down. I managed to prevent the picturebox from leaving the top of the form, but I do not know how to do it for bottom. I googled for hours, checked out the threads here but cannot seem to get the hang of it. Another thing, I prevented my picturebox from leaving the top of my form with the line:

```
if (spaceship.Top < ClientRectangle.Top) spaceship.Top = ClientRectangle.Top;
```

Although if someone keeps the arrow key up pressed, the movement seems rather clunky, but it works.

I tried using `spaceship.Location.Y` and modifying it, but didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below. Its easy to understand. Client's height can be max (spaceship's top + spaceship's height), if it greater means it has gone below the screen. So we have to restrict it at (Client's height - spaceship's height)

```
if (spaceship.Top + spaceship.Height > ClientRectangle.Height) 
    spaceship.Top = ClientRectangle.Height - spaceship.Height;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, and the explanation is pretty straight forward, so now I finally understand what its all about !

Comment: If it worked please mark it as answer, it will help others too.